# Support for 'configfailurepolicy' for TestNG in gradle

Tags: gradle, testng

Hi is there plan to add support for 'configfailurepolicy' property (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-m...) for TestNG in gradle ? 
It's really inconvenient that if some test fails in Before* phase, all other tests are skipped (even unrelated tests in different classes)

Comment: I guess it's much better to ask this question at: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle

Comment: I tried that 6 days ago - no response (http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/support_for_configfailurepolicy_for_testng)

Comment: Then the chance that You'll get response here is relatively low.

Comment: [gradle jira](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3149) was created for this

Comment: Added in Gradle 2.3. Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29790513