# testng how to set configfailurepolicy=true

Tags: java, gradle, testng

How to set 'configfailurepolicy=continue' for testng i'm using gradle to run the tests.
i tried 
`gradle clean test -Dgroups=abc -Dconfigurefailurepolicy=continue`
which didn't work I don't want the test cases to be failing after beforeClass method fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it in your `test` task:

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
        configFailurePolicy 'continue'
        includeGroups 'myTestGroup'
        ...
    }
}
```

but this property is available only in Gradle version 2.3+ http://gradle.org/docs/2.3/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/testng/TestNGOptions.html
https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3149

If you don't have newest version you can generate wrapper with task:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me where do i set this ?  is it in the build.gradle file ?

Comment: Yes, paste it to `build.gradle` file. You can change groups and add more properties from http://gradle.org/docs/2.3/groovydoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/testng/TestNGOptions.html if you need.

Comment: Well , im getting this  `No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGOptions.configFailurePolicy() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [continue] `

Comment: Here is my build.gradle file                                                                         'apply plugin: 'java'
defaultTasks = ['deploy']

/*
 * Task to generate Gradle Wrapper artifacts. This is
 * only required to update the wrapper itself and not
 * needed for regular builds.
 */
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.3'
        distributionUrl = 'abc.com'

test {
    useTestNG() {
        configFailurePolicy='continue'
        includeGroups 'myTestGroup'

    }
}

}

repositories {
        maven {
                url "abc.com"
        }


}'

Comment: Are you sure you are using Gradle 2.3 (`gradlew -version`)? Also from you previous comment it looks you have task `test` inner in task `wrapper` it's not correct both should be on 'top level'. Something like:`dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.8.21'
}

test {
    useTestNG() {
        configFailurePolicy 'continue'
        includeGroups 'unit'
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}`

Comment: I'm using` Gradle V-2.0` i cannot use 2.3 version because of some other issues. Is there any way where i can get this working in `V-2.0` itelf ?

Comment: This option is available since version 2.3 (https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3149), so no, Gradle doesn't support this in 2.0

Comment: i upgraded gradle to 2.3 an made the changes but still when @before or after class fails all other test cases are getting skipped.

Comment: Do i need to make any changes in  the testng side as well ?

Answer (score 0):

If that's a system property then set it in the test:

```
test {
     systemProperty 'configurefailuserpolicy', 'true'
}
```